# Getting the length of a string if it is passed in as a generic type

Tags: c#

I have a simple method that takes a generic type as an argument. I am trying to check if the generic type is a string and if so, return the length of the string.

This is what I have so far

```
public int ReturnLength<T>(T type)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
    {
         // Return the length of the string here
    }

    else
    {
        // Do other code here
    }
}
```

I have tried casting `type` to a string which didn't work

Does anyone have any ideas about how I could get the length of the string that is passed in if `type` is a string?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? You should consider creating several overloads of your function instead of trying to solve this as generic function.

Comment: What other types are you using this with that have a length? What do you do if it isn't a string?

Comment: I'm determining the size of unmanaged and managed types (including custom structures) which is why I needed to use a generic type. As a string (and any other reference type) has no defined size, I needed to handle that accordingly

Comment: Understood :) But remember that the _length_ of the string doesn't necessarily equate to how much memory it takes up. "hello" and "こんにちは" are both 5 characters, but (expressed as UTF8) "hello" takes up 5 bytes, and "こんにちは" takes up 15.

Comment: I realised that after a bit and so instead am just using the GetBytes method to get the actual byte representation of the string and work from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting will work, but you'll need to cast to object first:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
{
     string text = (string) (object) type;
     return text.Length;
}
```

I'd note that effectively switching on a type argument like this is *generally* an indication that it would be better not to write a generic method in the first place, but it's not a firm rule. Just something to consider.